# Why is the sender of an UIMenuItem action always nil?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, uimenucontroller

I've added an `UIMenuItem` instance to `UIMenuController`. When I tap in a text field twice, then I get that text editing menu with Copy, Cut, Paste, Lookup in Wikipedia.

This is my action method:

```
- (void)lookupInWikipedia:(id)sender {
    NSLog(%@"lookupInWikipedia: sender=%@", sender);
}
```

I get the `NSLog` when I select the "Lookup in Wikipedia" menu item. But sender is always nil.

Not even the `-canPerformAction:withSender:` method receives anything other than nil for sender.

```
- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender {
 NSLog(@"canPerformAction:withSender: = %@", sender);
 return YES;
}
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this a know framework bug?

Comment: Last time I checked the system returned UIMenuController. But that's as useful as nil. But I found another way to add blocks to UIMenuItem. https://github.com/steipete/PSMenuItem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also came across that once. Looks like a bug to me.