# iOS: Multiple UIMenuItems with single selector

Tags: iphone, ios, uimenucontroller, uimenuitem

I am new to iOS development and I am working on `UIMenuController`. It looks like we need to have a different selector for each `UIMenuItem`.

Is there a way to have a single selector and determine which item I clicked?

Can we send an argument to the selector so that we can identify which item we clicked?

This is the way i am initializing the menu item.

```
UIMenuItem *item = [[UIMenuItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Item 1" action:@selector(itemClicked:)];
```

Comment: Although not in the docs, I suspect `@selector(itemClicked:)` will have its argument set to the `UIMenuItem` instance which is clicked. Could you try that and report back if it's the case?

Comment: I've tried this, but the argument is set to UIMenuController. I don't think i can use that to identify the clicked item.

Comment: Unfortunately. Then you don't really have any other option.

Comment: if there is no other way, then it is awful... what if i need some 30 menu items... define 30 selectors? I may have to look for an alternative...

Comment: I start to feel that this is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What exactly are trying to do?

Comment: (And as a last resort, you might try to subclass `UIMenuController` and set a property on it each time a menu item is pressed, but I don't think you should be doing that.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9146670/ios-uimenucontroller-uimenuitem-how-to-determine-item-selected-with-generic-sel

Comment: @H2CO3: My requirement is simple. I have a UITableView with each row as a category. When I click any row, A menu should pop up and that menu is different for each row. So, I need to identify which menu item I have clicked as I have to take a different action based on that each item.

Comment: @sathvik That's similar to what I was talking about, thanks.

Comment: @rahul Take a look at the solution Sathvik linked.

Answer (score 1):

You can use blocks to handle the delegation like this

UIMenuItem.h

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) void (^onButtonClicked)(id btn);
```

UIMenuItem.m

```
@synthesize onButtonClicked;

- (IBAction)btnExpandClicked:(id)sender{

  self.onButtonClicked(sender);
}
```

which will be connected to each menu item

then in you UITableViewController.m

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath        *)indexPath {
...
item.onButtonClicked = ^(id btn) {
        // code that will run when the menu item is clicked "not the row of the table"
        // btn is the menu button clicked, you can implement a pop up based on each menu button clicked ( based on the tag for example )
    };
```