# Select a textView without select text inside?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextview

I have a `UITextView` inside of `UITableViewCell`. That `UITextView` I want be selectable but not text to. When the `Menu Controller` is appearing and i want to perform copy action, copy all text inside not just a part.

I want something like messenger app :

[image]

For the moment i have that :

[image]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It seems that you're looking for `tableView:shouldShowMenuForRowAtIndexPath:` method of `UITableViewDelegate`

Comment: it's depend on your implement , you can disable  the interaction of your text view and add your custom UIMenu action on it and call them by gesture

Comment: @Larme i think will be no pussible because i have two Text Views in cell, i forget to say that.

Answer (score 1):

In fact it's not quite so easy, as on the road show up some strange stuff, but I managed to create a customized one.

The steps are as following:

1. Create a subclass of `UITextView`
2. Override `canPerformAction:
   withSender:` for filtering the default actions of the menu
   that pops up.
3. Configuring `textView` in order not to be able to **edit** or
   **select**.
4. Editing `UIMenuController` items which provide the actions and buttons on the menu
5. Add different selectors for each `UIMenuItem` **** (That is because the sender of the selector is not an `UIMenuItem`, but a `UIMenuController` which leads to another matter. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9874092/2664437) for more info. A [gist](https://gist.github.com/eridbardhaj/768351b7c3632ae015ac) by me for that)

### Code

No more talking so here is the code:

**EBCustomTextView.h**

```
//
//  EBCustomTextView.h
//  TestProject
//
//  Created by Erid Bardhaj on 3/8/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 Erid Bardhaj. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, EBCustomTextViewMenuAction) {
    EBCustomTextViewMenuActionCopy,
    EBCustomTextViewMenuActionDefine,
    EBCustomTextViewMenuActionRead
};

@class EBCustomTextView;
@protocol EBCustomTextViewMenuActionDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)customTextView:(EBCustomTextView *)textView didSelectMenuAction:(EBCustomTextViewMenuAction)action;

@end

@interface EBCustomTextView : UITextView

@property (weak, nonatomic) id<EBCustomTextViewMenuActionDelegate> menuActionDelegate;

@end
```

**EBCustomTextView.m**

```
//
//  EBCustomTextView.m
//  TestProject
//
//  Created by Erid Bardhaj on 3/8/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 Erid Bardhaj. All rights reserved.
//

#import "EBCustomTextView.h"

@implementation EBCustomTextView {
    EBCustomTextViewMenuAction currentAction;
}

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];

    // Configure the textView
    self.editable = NO;
    self.selectable = NO;
}

#pragma mark - Datasource

- (NSArray *)items {
    UIMenuItem *item = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Copy" action:@selector(copyMenuItemPressed)];
    UIMenuItem *item1 = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Define" action:@selector(defineMenuItemPressed)];
    UIMenuItem *item2 = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Read" action:@selector(readMenuItemPressed)];

    return @[item, item1, item2];
}


#pragma mark - Actions

- (void)copyMenuItemPressed {
    if ([self.menuActionDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(customTextView:didSelectMenuAction:)]) {
        [self.menuActionDelegate customTextView:self didSelectMenuAction:EBCustomTextViewMenuActionCopy];
    }
}

- (void)defineMenuItemPressed {
    if ([self.menuActionDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(customTextView:didSelectMenuAction:)]) {
        [self.menuActionDelegate customTextView:self didSelectMenuAction:EBCustomTextViewMenuActionDefine];
    }
}

- (void)readMenuItemPressed {
    if ([self.menuActionDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(customTextView:didSelectMenuAction:)]) {
        [self.menuActionDelegate customTextView:self didSelectMenuAction:EBCustomTextViewMenuActionRead];
    }
}

#pragma mark - Private

- (void)menuItemPressedAtIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    currentAction = index;

    if ([self.menuActionDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(customTextView:didSelectMenuAction:)]) {
        [self.menuActionDelegate customTextView:self didSelectMenuAction:currentAction];
    }
}

#pragma mark Helpers

- (void)showMenuController {
    UIMenuController *theMenu = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController];
    theMenu.menuItems = [self items];
    [theMenu update];

    CGRect selectionRect = CGRectMake (0, 0, self.contentSize.width, self.contentSize.height);
    [theMenu setTargetRect:selectionRect inView:self];
    [theMenu setMenuVisible:(theMenu.isMenuVisible) ? NO : YES animated:YES];
}

#pragma mark - Overridings

- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender {
    // Filter any action for this textView except our custom ones
    if (action == @selector(copyMenuItemPressed) || action == @selector(defineMenuItemPressed) || action == @selector(readMenuItemPressed)) {
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *theTouch = [touches anyObject];

    if ([theTouch tapCount] == 1  && [self becomeFirstResponder]) {
        [self showMenuController];
    }
}


@end
```

### Implementation

Set your textView's class to `EBCustomTextView` and conform to `EBCustomTextViewMenuActionDelegate`

**Interface**

```
@interface ViewController () <EBCustomTextViewMenuActionDelegate>
```

**viewDidLoad**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.textView.menuActionDelegate = self;
}
```

**Protocol conformance**

```
#pragma mark - Delegation

#pragma mark EBCustomTextViewMenuActionDelegate 

- (void)customTextView:(EBCustomTextView *)textView didSelectMenuAction:(EBCustomTextViewMenuAction)action {
    switch (action) {
        case EBCustomTextViewMenuActionCopy:
            NSLog(@"Copy Action");
            break;

        case EBCustomTextViewMenuActionRead:
            NSLog(@"Read Action");
            break;

        case EBCustomTextViewMenuActionDefine:
            NSLog(@"Define Action");
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

### Output

[image]

Enjoy :)

Comment: Thank you, Your answer looks really good, but i solve already my problem. I will post my solution to!

Answer (score 0):

you have to use

```
[UITextView selectAll:self];
```

or (with specific range)

```
UITextView.selectedRange = NSMakeRange(0, 5);
```

or   add `txtview.delegate = self;`

```
- (BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [textView selectAll:nil];  //nil or self as per needed
    });
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use UILongPressGestureRecognizer Gesture**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
{
   UITextView * txtV;
   UILongPressGestureRecognizer * longPressGestureRecognizer;
}
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];

   txtV=[[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 50, 280, 300)];
   txtV.text = @"Jai Maharashtra";
   txtV.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
   txtV.selectable=NO;
   txtV.editable=NO;
   txtV.font= [UIFont italicSystemFontOfSize:[UIFont systemFontSize]];
   [self.view addSubview:txtV];

   longPressGestureRecognizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPressGesture:)];
   longPressGestureRecognizer.delegate=self;
   [txtV addGestureRecognizer:longPressGestureRecognizer];
}

- (void)longPressGesture:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
       txtV.selectable=YES;
       [txtV selectAll:self];
    }
}

-(BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
{
    [txtV selectAll:self];

    if (action == @selector(cut:))
    {
       return YES;
    }
    if (action == @selector(selectAll:))
    {
      return YES;
    }
    if (action == @selector(copy:))
    {
      return YES;
    }
    if (action == @selector(delete:))
    {
      return YES;
    }

    txtV.selectable=NO;
    return YES;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

First i start with create for every `UITextView` in cell a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` to recognize  long press.

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` i just add that code :

```
 UILongPressGestureRecognizer *recognizer1 = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPressText1:)];
 messageRecognizer.delaysTouchesBegan = YES;

 UILongPressGestureRecognizer *recognizer2 = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPressText2:)];
 translateRecognizer.delaysTouchesBegan = YES;


 [cell.backgroundViewText1 addGestureRecognizer:recognizer1];
 [cell.backgroundViewText2 addGestureRecognizer:recognizer2];
```

I use two different selectors because i need to know which text to get from cell.

After the  methods :

```
    -(void)handleLongPressText1:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    if ([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        CGPoint p = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.tableView];
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:p];
        if (indexPath == nil){
            NSLog(@"couldn't find index path");
        } else {
            [self becomeFirstResponder];

            UIMenuController *menuController = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController];
            UIMenuItem *resetMenuItem = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Copy" action:@selector(copyMethod)];
            UIMenuItem *menuItem = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Read" action:@selector(readButtonAction)];

            [menuController setMenuItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:resetMenuItem,menuItem, nil]];
            CGRect rect =gestureRecognizer.view.frame;
            NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(rect));
            [menuController setTargetRect:gestureRecognizer.view.frame inView:[[gestureRecognizer view] superview]];
            [menuController setMenuVisible:YES animated:YES];

        }
    }
}

    -(void)handleLongPressText2:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    if ([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        CGPoint p = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.tableView];
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:p];
        if (indexPath == nil){
            NSLog(@"couldn't find index path");
        } else {
            [self becomeFirstResponder];

            UIMenuController *menuController = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController];
            UIMenuItem *resetMenuItem = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Copy" action:@selector(copyMethod)];
            UIMenuItem *menuItem = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Read" action:@selector(readButtonAction)];

            [menuController setMenuItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:resetMenuItem,menuItem, nil]];
            CGRect rect =gestureRecognizer.view.frame;
            NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(rect));
            [menuController setTargetRect:gestureRecognizer.view.frame inView:[[gestureRecognizer view] superview]];
            [menuController setMenuVisible:YES animated:YES];
        }
    }
}
```

And for disable all default items in `UIMenuController` use above code

```
- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)iAction withSender:(id)iSender {
SEL copySelector = NSSelectorFromString(@"copyMethod");
SEL readSeletor = NSSelectorFromString(@"readButtonAction");

if (iAction == copySelector) {
    return YES;
}else if (iAction ==readSeletor){
    return YES;
}else{
    return NO;
}


return NO;
}
```